# Jquery scroll() Compatibilidade com IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

E ae pessoal, tudo bem?
Pessoal, estou com um probleminha, tenho um evento JQuery scroll(), só que estou com problema de compatibilidade com o Microsoft Edge (IE), segue o código:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $('html, body').scrollTop();

    if(scrollTop >= 40){
        $('.header-menu').css('position', 'fixed');
        $('.header-menu').css('top', '0');
        $('.header-menu').css('left', '0');
        $('.header-menu').css('right', '0');
    }else if(scrollTop <= 40){
        $('.header-menu').css('position', 'relative');      
    }

    if(scrollTop >= 380){
        $('.sub-menu').css('position', 'fixed');
        $('.sub-menu').css('top', '140px');
        $('.sub-menu').css('right', '40px');
    }else if(scrollTop <= 500){
        $('.sub-menu').css('position', 'absolute');
        $('.sub-menu').css('top', '0');
    }

});
```

OBS: Testei também naquele navegador semelhante ao Chrome, -Chromium- e também não funcionou... Já troquei também o window por document e Nn funcionou

Comment: mas o que exatamente não funcionou? dá algum erro?

Comment: Ops, acabei de verificar, o evento scroll funciona, então o problema está no scrollTop.

Comment: se quiser olhar o que pretendo fazer, é só acessar a página http://ges.rf.gd pelo Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `$('html, body').scrollTop();` só vai pegar o valor do primeiro que encontrar, como toda página gera as tags html e body (conteudo ou não no source do HTML), ele sempre vai buscar o `scrollTop` de html

E como no IE provavelmente o scroll não seja no mesmo elemento que é no Firefox e Chrome então deve usar a global `window.`, assim:

```
 $(window).scrollTop();
```

Provavelmente assim resolve e até simplifica (e ficará "um pouco mais rápido", já que não precisará chamar diversas vezes o `$(...)`):

```
var $w = $(window);

$w.scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $w.scrollTop();
    var headermenu = $('.header-menu');
    var submenu = $('.sub-menu');

    if(scrollTop >= 40){
        headermenu.css({
            'position': 'fixed',
            'top': '0',
            'left': '0',
            'right': '0'
        });
    }else if(scrollTop <= 40){
        headermenu.css('position', 'relative');      
    }

    if(scrollTop >= 380){
        submenu.css({
            'position': 'fixed',
            'top': '140px',
            'right': '40px'
        });
    }else if(scrollTop <= 500){
        submenu.css({
            'position': 'absolute',
            'top': '0'
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: Justamentee, muitoo obrigado, eu não sabia desse pequeno detalhe, valeu cara